# Imported assets in Xcode are huge

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to make an iOS app in Xcode and the problem that I'm having is that the images that I have imported to use are huge. I first designed my app in photoshop and then extracted each asset out separately. I made sure that everything is the correct size. Every asset adds up to the iPhone retina resolution (1136 x 640).
But when I put these assets into the storyboard they are too big and go off of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you called them like imageName@2x.png and that you put them in the `2x` section in the `asset catalog`. Otherwise the images would be treated as non retina images and they would be displayed in the double size.

Check that you are viewing them at the 4" iPhone, since the 3,5" is only 960px height.

Or you might have a opaque status bar, navigation bar or tab bar that decreases the available screenheight.